# Static file was not found after Django server was run

Tags: django, static

I have followed book recommendations and other solutions but it does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Result:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 16, 2018 - 20:37:29
Django version 2.0.5, using settings 'locallibrary.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.4:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

[16/Jul/2018 20:56:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1457

[16/Jul/2018 20:56:46] "GET /static/catalog/css/catalog.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1794

# structure

Development

manage.py

<Project> 
    ( _init_.py,  settings.py,  urls.py, wsgi.py,   rootstatic(to collect information) )

<Catalog> 
    (_init_.py, models.py, tests.py, views.py, static [catalog/css/catalog.css/]



#settings

DEBUG = True
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '%s/rootstatic/' % (BASE_DIR)


TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['%s/templates/'% (PROJECT_DIR),],
    'APP_DIRS': True,

      },
    ]




# urls
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

# template
<link href="{% static 'catalog/css/catalog.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant file tree?

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Comment: project/
        manage.py
        project/ --> (settings.py, etc)
        catalog/ --> (models.py, views.py, etc)
            static/catalog/css